# How to use 1D string type array in place of double type two dimensional jagged array in c#?

Tags: c#

I have data in this form:

```
double[][] rawData = new double[3][];
rawData[0] = new double[] { 65.0, 220.0 };
rawData[1] = new double[] { 73.0, 160.0 };
rawData[2] = new double[] { 59.0, 110.0 };
```

Now I want to import data from text file and use in place of this array data. I want double type jagged array for text file data too.

Data of each row in file is of form: `5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2`

There are total 150 rows in text file. I want to read file line by line, split by comma and save each line in double type array as in case of `rawData[]][]`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is a site to help you learn, where as it seems like you are simply asking for an answer.

Comment: The word `double` means _real number stored with precision 15-16 decimal places_ (see [double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/678hzkk9.aspx)).
If you want to store an array of strings, then you need to declare a `string[][] rawData` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *Linq*, you have to

1. *Read* file line by line
2. *Split* each line into `items` by comma
3. *Convert* each item into `Double`
4. *Materialize* items into (inner) array
5. *Materialize* lines into (outer) array

Implementation

```
  // let txt file being a CSV-like one
  Double[][] data = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
    .Where(line => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim())) // to remove empty lines if any
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Select(items => items
      .Select(item => Double.Parse(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
      .ToArray()) // inner array
    .ToArray();   // outer array
```

Comment: Trying above mentioned method gives an error "when converting a string to DateTime, parse the string parse the string to take the date before putting each value into DateTime object"

Comment: @bint-e shafiq: As you can see there's no `DateTime` in my code fragment; so it's your routine that throws the exception; usual cause is incorrect `DateTime.Parse();` call (my code uses `Double.Parse` - `Double`, not `DateTime`)

Comment: I can see there is no DateTime in your code. Actually i am new to c# so unable to get why this error is occurring. I have tried to use Covert.ToDouble but it gives same error in this case too. What do you mean by 'its routine that throws the exception.' How can it be handled?

Comment: Thanks, its working now. There were some empty lines in text file that were causing issue. Now the code is working.

Comment: @bint-e shafiq: just add `.Where(line => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()))` - see my edit - to ignore empty lines